# onclick event of imageview in a custom cell of a listview

Tags: java, android

I'm new in android, I'm write an application which has an imageView containing an image of "delete sign" in a custom cell of a listview. Now I'm trying to implement the click event of the imageView which is in a custom cell. But didn't find any solution, please help me to implement onclick event of imageview and checkbox as well.

I'm not willing to implement the cell onclick event, but will to implement the onclick event of imageview or button or a checkbox inside a cell, please help me how could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the getView of your adapter. This is the short version.
replace yourlayout and your imageview with the id's to your ImageView and Layout

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourLayout, null);
    convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageview).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               // your click handling code here. 
            }
        });
     return convertView;
}
```

of course you will want to reuse the convert view and other good ListView practices, but this should get you started.